# Opening Windows files with ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, file

Is it possible to open files (XML, Word) on windows (In the default program)?
I am using windows 7 and the latest ruby version (1.9.2).

Answer (score 4):

Try using a "system" call to run the "start" command, like so:

```
system("start hello.doc") # Should launch MS Word.
system("start file.xml") # Should launch an XML viewer.
```

Comment: For some reason, on my system this always opens a terminal, no matter the file format :(

Comment: Never mind. I my command added quotes (`"`) around the file path, which is no good on windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting your Ruby script to open Word files and manipulate them, then you may want to look into the win32ole library.